# For a negative series that is becoming more positive, is this an increase or decrease in magntiude?

Tags: definition

There is a question in my textbook that asks if the **magnitude** of the Gibbs free energy (far right column) increases or decreases as the compound becomes longer (i.e. as you go from the top of the table to the bottom).

Does magnitude mean absolute value?

I.e. $|-51| > |-33| > |-23| > |-8|$ , hence a decrease in magntiude as you move down the table.

Or does magnitude mean how positive it is?

[image: Question stimulus material]

Comment: Magnitude means absolute value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jnyan says it all, and so does http://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-magnitude-definition-lesson-quiz.html.  The magnitude of a number is its absolute value.